# How to Implement step Progress bar like flipkart delivery report bar

Tags: asp.net

I need to implement a progress bar which shows the background processes step wise when i click on a submit button. When i click on the button the process should start which involves steps like patch started, patch in process, patch completed, process completed and  at the same time it should show the steps happening on progress bar.
For example, delivery report bar on the flipkart.
What needs to be done?
Im using asp.net

Thank you

Comment: There is already stuff on the internet regarding this, suggesting you to read article implement it:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/progress-bar-in-Asp-Net2/ and this :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113418/ASP-NET-File-Upload-with-Progress-Bar

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SignalR** in this case, which allows server code to send asynchronous notifications to client-side web applications.
This [link](http://growingtech.blogspot.com/2012/10/progress-bar-for-long-running-process.html) can help you to understand how you can implement in asp.net.